# Rules Engine Sitecore 8 MVC

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I'm currently doing a project that is in need of conditional rules. I've seen this guide in making a simple rule in Sitecore 6.5 http://www.newguid.net/sitecore/2011/sitecore-rules-engine-how-to-create-a-custom-condition/ but the problem is that making rules in Sitecore 8 is slightly different. Do you guys have any sample of making rules in Sitecore 8 as well as implementing it in MVC. Thanks.

Comment: Those "global rules" don't work with MVC I'm afraid, Rules work if you apply them individually to a component but the condition/action combination as a single definition do not work. For the changes to the rules, you can read this article: https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2013/11/limiting-conditions-and-actions-with-sitecore-71.aspx